# Jquery returning undefined

Tags: jquery, return

am using tabswitch from 
http://www.hieu.co.uk/blog/index.php/tabswitch/

am trying to add extra functionality to return the total number of tabs
am trying to return a value within the function 
the alert statement in getLength outputs the correct value 
but the value returned is undefined

here is my code:

```
//the function within tabswitch function:
var getLength = function(){
   var $totalPages = parseInt((Obj.length));
   alert('getLength function totalPages = '+$totalPages);
   $('.pagetotal').html(' '+$totalPages); //this correctly sets the element to the correct value
   return ($totalPages); // this returns undefined?
}

function setTabIndex(){
   $totalPages = $('.SlideTab').tabSwitch('getlength'); //undefined?
   $mypage = parseInt($(".SlideTab").tabSwitch('index')+1);
   $currentIndex = parseInt($(".SlideTab").tabSwitch('index'));
   $('.pageon').html('Page '+$mypage+' of');
   alert('totalPages = '+$totalPages+' myPage = '+$mypage+' currentindex = '+$currentIndex); //returns undefined for total pages??  
   setButtons();
};
```

the full tabswitch code:

```
/*
 * .tabSwitch
 * Version: 1.0
 * http://www.hieu.co.uk/blog/index.php/tabswitch/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Hieu Pham - http://www.hieu.co.uk
 * COMMON DEVELOPMENT AND DISTRIBUTION LICENSE (CDDL)
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/cddl1.php
 *
 * Date: 14/04/2009
 */
(function($){
    $.fn.tabSwitch = function(command, Arguements, EndFunction) {
        //Default value should be set here
        var defaults = {
            type    :   "toggle", //Type of effect
            cols    :   2, //This only used when you're using type = table
            toggle  :   "fade", //This specific which type of toggle effect
            ease    :   40, 
            easeType:   "linear", //This isn't work for this version yet
            loopback:   0, //If it's 1 it will loop when it reach the ends
            width   :   400, // Size of the viewport
            height  :   400,
            index   :   0, //The current tab index
            speed   :   500, //Speed of the animation
            interval:   5000, //The interval of auto-animate
            step    :   1, //How many step you want to use in moveStep
            wrapperClass : "", //You could add extra class for the wraper
            viewportClass : "" //You could add extra class for the viewport
        };

        var Args = $.extend(defaults, Arguements);
        var Obj = this; 

        var $totalPages = (Obj.length);

        //For quicker access
        var jFirstObj = Obj.eq(1);
        var DOMFirstObj = Obj.eq(1).get(0); 
        if(!$.isFunction(EndFunction)){
            //Set the index in the cache
            var Callback = function(){
                $.data(DOMFirstObj, "index", Args.index);
            };
        }
        else{
            var Callback = function(){
                $.data(DOMFirstObj, "index", Args.index);
                EndFunction();
            };
        }
        //Back up orginal information
        StoreToCache = function(){
            //Now store the tab type in the cache for further use
            $.data(DOMFirstObj, "type", Args.type);
            $.data(DOMFirstObj, "toggle", Args.toggle);
            $.data(DOMFirstObj, "cols", Args.cols);
            $.data(DOMFirstObj, "ease", Args.ease);
            $.data(DOMFirstObj, "easeType", Args.easeType);
            $.data(DOMFirstObj, "index", Args.index);
            $.data(DOMFirstObj, "loopback", Args.loopback);
            //Before do anything to the object, keep a backup so we could revert it
            if(jFirstObj.attr('style')){
                $.data(DOMFirstObj, "orgAttr", jFirstObj.attr('style'));
            }else{
                $.data(DOMFirstObj, "orgAttr", "");
            }
        }
        //Remove all the data in cache and reset the object back to original
        backFromCache = function(){
            Obj.attr('style',$.data(DOMFirstObj, "orgAttr"));
            var ViewPortObj = $("#ViewPort"+$.data(DOMFirstObj));
            ViewPortObj.replaceWith(Obj);
            //Remove auto if it's running
            stopAuto();
            //Clear cacke
            $.removeData(DOMFirstObj);
        }
        //Execute when input comment is create
        var createTab = function(){
            //Back up orginal information
            StoreToCache(); 
            //Construct the form
            //Set all the CSS for the list div, this;s the common setting for all type of tab
            if(Args.width)  Obj.width(Args.width);
            if(Args.height) Obj.height(Args.height);            
            //A big wraper around and change some CSS of the wrap
            var WraperSelector = "WideDiv" + $.data(DOMFirstObj);
            Obj.wrapAll("<div id='"+WraperSelector +"'></div>");
            var WraperObj = $("#"+WraperSelector);
            WraperObj.addClass(Args.wraperClass);
            WraperObj.css({"position":"relative"});
            WraperObj.wrap("<div id='" +WraperSelector.replace("WideDiv","ViewPort") + "'></div>")
            //Now create the viewport with the input size
            var ViewPortObj = $("#" + WraperSelector.replace("WideDiv","ViewPort"));
            ViewPortObj.width(Args.width);
            ViewPortObj.height(Args.height);
            ViewPortObj.css({"display":"block","overflow":"hidden","position":"relative"});                 
            ViewPortObj.addClass(Args.viewportClass);
            switch(Args.type)
            {
                case "slide":
                    Obj.css({"float":"left"});
                    //A big wraper around and change some CSS of the wrap
                    WraperObj.width((Args.width+2) * Obj.length);
                    //Now create the viewport with the input size
                    break;
                case "scroll":
                    //A big wraper around and change some CSS of the wrap               
                    WraperObj.width(Args.width);
                    WraperObj.height((Args.height+2) * Obj.length);
                    break;
                case "toggle":
                    WraperObj.width(Args.width);
                    WraperObj.height(Args.height);
                    Obj.css({"position":"absolute", "left": "-999px"});
                    Obj.eq(Args.index).css({"left":"0px", "top":"0px"});
                    Obj.eq(Args.index).css("opacity", 1);
                    break;
                case "table":
                    WraperObj.width(Args.width*Args.cols);
                    Obj.css("float", "left");
            }
            moveTo();
        }

        var getLength = function(){
            //$totalPages = parseInt((Obj.length));
            alert('getLength function totalPages = '+$totalPages);
            $('.pagetotal').html(' '+$totalPages);
            return ($totalPages);
        }
        // Move object to a position set by Args.Index
        var moveTo = function(){

            //get the easeLevel from the cache
            var ease = 0;
            //Check if the next idx is out of the limit or not
            if(!Args.easeType){
                Args.easeType = (DOMFirstObj, "easeType");
            }
            if(Args.index > Obj.length -1 ){
                if($.data(DOMFirstObj, "loopback")!=0){
                    Args.index = 0;
                    ease = -$.data(DOMFirstObj, "ease");
                }
                else return;
            }
            if(Args.index < 0 ){
                if($.data(DOMFirstObj, "loopback")!=0){                 
                    Args.index = Obj.length-1;
                    ease = $.data(DOMFirstObj, "ease");
                } else return;
            }   
            var WraperSelector = "WideDiv" + $.data(DOMFirstObj);               
            var WraperObj = $("#"+WraperSelector);
            //See what type of effect we stimulate
            switch($.data(DOMFirstObj, "type")){
                case 'slide':
                    //Get how much ease we set and start the animation
                    if(ease!=0){
                        var easeLevel = (parseInt(WraperObj.css("left").replace("px",""))+ease);
                        WraperObj.animate({left: easeLevel+"px"}, Args.speed, function(){
                            WraperObj.animate({left:-(Obj.outerWidth(true) * Args.index)+"px"}, Args.speed, Args.easeType, Callback());         
                        });
                    }else{
                        WraperObj.animate({left:-(Obj.outerWidth(true) * Args.index)+"px"}, Args.speed, Args.easeType, Callback());         
                    }               
                break;
                case 'scroll':
                    //Get how much ease we set and start the animation
                    if(ease!=0){
                        var easeLevel = (parseInt(WraperObj.css("top").replace("px",""))+ease);
                        WraperObj.animate({top: easeLevel+"px"}, Args.speed, function(){
                            WraperObj.animate({top:-(Obj.outerHeight(true) * Args.index)+"px"}, Args.speed, Args.easeType, Callback());         
                        });
                    }else{
                        WraperObj.animate({top:-(Obj.outerHeight(true) * Args.index)+"px"}, Args.speed, Args.easeType, Callback());         
                    }
                break;
                case 'toggle':
                    //move the new one on top of the old div
                    Obj.eq(Args.index).css({"left":"0px", "top":"0px"});
                    switch($.data(DOMFirstObj, "toggle"))
                    {
                        case "fade":
                            Obj.eq(Args.index).css({"opacity":0});                                              
                            Obj.eq(Args.index).animate({"opacity":1},Args.speed);
                            if($.data(DOMFirstObj, "index")!=Args.index){
                                Obj.eq($.data(DOMFirstObj, "index")).animate({"opacity":0},Args.speed, function(){
                                    $(this).css("left",-999);
                                    Callback();
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case "toggle":
                            if($.data(DOMFirstObj, "index")!=Args.index){                           
                                Obj.eq(Args.index).css({"display":"none"});
                                Obj.eq($.data(DOMFirstObj, "index")).slideUp(Args.speed,  function(){
                                    Obj.eq(Args.index).slideDown(Args.speed, function(){Callback();});                          
                                    $(this).css("left",-999);                                                   
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case "show":
                            if($.data(DOMFirstObj, "index")!=Args.index){                                       
                                Obj.eq(Args.index).css({"display":"none"});
                                Obj.eq($.data(DOMFirstObj, "index")).hide(Args.speed, function(){
                                    Obj.eq(Args.index).show(Args.speed,function(){Callback();});                            
                                    $(this).css("left",-999);                                                   
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case "noeffect":
                            if($.data(DOMFirstObj, "index")!=Args.index){               
                                Obj.eq($.data(DOMFirstObj, "index")).css("left", -999);
                                Callback();
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "table":
                    var cols = $.data(DOMFirstObj, "cols");
                    //Where the next idx in the table
                    var nextX = -(Args.index % cols) * Obj.width();
                    var nextY = -Math.floor(Args.index / cols) * Obj.height();
                    //Move horizontal first
                    WraperObj.animate({"left": nextX}, Args.speed, Args.easeType, function(){
                        WraperObj.animate({"top": nextY}, Args.speed, Args.easeType, Callback());
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    $('html,body').animate({"scrollTop":Obj.eq(Args.index).offset().top},Args.speed);
                break;

            }
        };

        //Move by steps
        moveStep = function(){
            var currentIdx = $.data(DOMFirstObj, "index");
            //Calculate the next index
            Args.index = parseInt(currentIdx) + parseInt(Args.step);
            //Then move to it
            moveTo();
        }
        //Set it run auto
        startAuto = function(){
            //Save the autoswitch into memory and start it
            $.data(DOMFirstObj, "AutoSwitch", setInterval(moveStep, Args.interval));
        }
        //Stop the auto
        stopAuto = function(){
            //Stop the interval and clear the cache
            clearInterval($.data(DOMFirstObj, "AutoSwitch"));
            $.removeData(DOMFirstObj, "AutoSwitch");
        }
        //Toggle auto
        toggleAuto = function(){
            if(isAuto()){
                stopAuto();
            }else{
                startAuto();
            }
        }
        //Return if this is auto or not
        isAuto = function(){
            if($.data(DOMFirstObj, "AutoSwitch")){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }       
        }
        if(!command) command = "";
        //Check what user want
        switch(command.toLowerCase()){
            case "index": 
                if($.data(DOMFirstObj, "index")){
                    return $.data(DOMFirstObj, "index");
                }else{
                    return 0;
                }
                break;
            case "moveto":
                moveTo();
                break;
            case "movestep":
                moveStep();
                break;
            case "destroy":
                backFromCache();
                break;
            case "create":
                createTab();
                break;
            case "isauto":
                return isAuto();
                break;
            case "toggleauto":
                toggleAuto();
                break;
            case "startauto":
                startAuto();
                break;
            case "stopauto":
                stopAuto();
                break;
            case "getlength":
                getLength();
                break;
            case "pagecount":
                pageCount();
                break;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please click the "edit" link and look at the formatting tips shown to the right of the editing area. They tell you how to format code, etc. There's also an orange **[?]** that will give you more information. (Update: Looks like Nick formatted it for you. But please do take a look for next time.)

Comment: ahh thanks for that, my first post here, of many to come i imagine!!!

Answer (score 1):

Casing matters here, you'll *probably* need to call `getLength` not `getlength`, like this:

```
$totalPages = $('.SlideTab').tabSwitch('getLength');
```

Also you're alerting and returning different variables, you need to also use `$totalPages` in your [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) call as well:

```
$('.pagetotal').html(' '+$totalPages);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, the case is not a problem as the function calls within tabswitch are all converted to lowercase:

Comment: @Dizzy - Make sure you're using the same variable then, currently you're appending an undefined one, yet alerting and returning the proper one.